# Get response time per day of week

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I have 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `ticket` (
  `tid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sid` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `open_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tid`),
  KEY `sid` (`sid`,`open_date`),
  KEY `open_date` (`open_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `ticket_reply` (
  `rid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `reply_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`rid`),
  KEY `tid` (`tid`,`reply_date`),
  KEY `reply_date` (`reply_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `subscription` (
  `sid` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `response_time` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '24',
  PRIMARY KEY (`sid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I'm trying to get the sum of response times the first ticket reply is from when the ticket was opened and group it by DAYNAME (maybe by MONTH also). Currently I have this SQL:

```
SELECT
     t.tid,
    DAYNAME(t.open_date) AS day_opened,
    SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, t.open_date, tr.reply_date)) AS num_min,
    SUM(s.response_time * 60) AS response_time_min
FROM ticket t
INNER JOIN ticket_reply tr ON tr.tid = t.tid
INNER JOIN subscription s ON s.sid = t.sid
GROUP BY 
    t.tid #group by tid as ticket_reply may return many
ORDER BY t.open_date DESC;
```

So first challenge I have is getting the first ticket_reply row which I solved by GROUP BY, I tried to get a subquery in the join but it was still returning a row per ticket_reply row.

So now I want to start grouping by DAYNAME and maybe MONTH but if I add it to the GROUP BY it doesn't group:

```
GROUP BY
   t.tid,
   DAYNAME(t.open_date)
```

Have tried DAYNAME before tid but that didn't make any difference.

So I have a couple questions, is there a better way to get the first row in ticket_reply and then group by the DAYNAME? I have a feeling getting the first row in a subquery may fix the grouping.

Comment: why not just `GROUP BY DATE(t.open_date)`?? or DAY() MONTH() YEAR() theres a few options to try.. have you tried any of these?

Comment: you should probably use a subquery as well.. `WHERE t.open_date IN(select max(open_date) from ...`

Answer (score 0):

It is grouping, but because you have `t.tid` in the `GROUP BY` clause, and the `tid` column is unique in the `ticket` table, multiple rows from `ticket` are not getting collapsed, each is going to be on its own row.

It's not exactly clear what result you want to return.

(The `SUM(s.response_time)` expression in the SELECT list seems a bit odd, given that you could be matching multiple rows from `ticket_reply`.)

Given your existing statement, it looks like you might want to use an inline view to return the "earliest" `reply_date` for each ticket, in place of the reference to the `ticket_reply` table.

```
   JOIN /*ticket_reply*/
        ( SELECT r.tid
               , MIN(r.reply_date) AS reply_date
            FROM ticket_reply r
           GROUP BY r.tid
        ) tr ON tr.tid = t.tid
```

(Unfortunately, materializing the inline view (populating and accessing an intermediate "derived table") can be the source of a performance issue.)

As another option, rather than performing a JOIN operation, you could consider using a correlated subquery in the `SELECT` list. That is, in place of the reference to `tr.reply_date`, you could do something like:

```
    (SELECT MIN(r.reply_date) FROM ticket_reply r WHERE r.tid = t.tid)
```

and remove the JOIN to the `ticket_reply` table.

But, repeated execution of that subquery (once for each row returned), can also be a performance issue for large sets.

---

But the "big" question is whether you need to add up `s.response_time` for each occurrence of a matching `ticket_reply` (as your current query is doing), or whether you just need to include the `s.response_time` once for each `ticket`?

That is, if there are three `ticket_reply` for a given `ticket`, do we need to "triple" the value of `response_time` that we add to the row?

If you need to include the `response_time` in the total for each `ticket_reply, then this:

```
SELECT DAYNAME(t.open_date) AS day_opened
     , SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, t.open_date, tr.reply_date)) AS num_min
     , SUM(s.response_time) * 60 * tr.cnt_replies AS response_time_min
  FROM ticket t
  JOIN ( SELECT r.tid
              , MIN(r.reply_date) AS reply_date
              , COUNT(1) AS cnt_replies
           FROM ticket_reply r
          GROUP BY r.tid
       ) tr
    ON tr.tid = t.tid
  JOIN subscription s 
    ON s.sid = t.sid
 GROUP 
    BY day_opened
```

If you only need to include the `response_time` in the total once for each `ticket`, remove the references to `cnt_replies`:

```
SELECT DAYNAME(t.open_date) AS day_opened
     , SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, t.open_date, tr.reply_date)) AS num_min
     , SUM(s.response_time) * 60 AS response_time_min
  FROM ticket t
  JOIN ( SELECT r.tid
              , MIN(r.reply_date) AS reply_date
           FROM ticket_reply r
          GROUP BY r.tid
       ) tr
    ON tr.tid = t.tid
  JOIN subscription s 
    ON s.sid = t.sid
 GROUP 
    BY day_opened
```

To `GROUP BY` month, just change the first expression in the SELECT list, and the reference in the GROUP BY clause.